# Why does model look thinner in Cycles than in Eevee?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, eevee-render-engine

My model looks ok in shader editor and Eevee but "thinner" in Cycles. Seems like someting wrong with camera settings and perspective but I use the same camera for both renders.
Please help me to understand why and how to fix it. [image]

Comment: Is there a displacement shader involved, here, somewhere?

Comment: I use displacement map

Comment: Eevee does not displace, it just uses normal mapping. Cycles does displace. So it may just be a question of making sure the displacement is applied correctly, with the right midpoint and scale, in the right color/data - space, etc. Maybe you could show that part of your node-tree.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know that. The problem was solved by scaling my model. It was too big, mb that's why displacement map didn't apply correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't actually thinner. This is the lighting. Adjust your world background color, sun lamps, and any other lamps, reflectors, and mesh lights you may have in the scene to get a better result. My advice would be to place a sun lamp pointing directly above your model for best lighting, with the strength set to 1.5.

Comment: I don't know about that.. e.g. the gaps between the fingers?

Comment: It's going to sound pretty jank, but I checked 5 points on the bracer with calipers, its all the same size. Looks like only the fingers are off.

Comment: so maybe a mix of lighting and, like robin said, a displacement map that is just on the glove material?